# Constant Adobe Flash, browser and laptop crashes - reason?

Tags: memory, troubleshooting, logging, flash-player, adobe-flash

For the last two days I have had constant problems with my browser and laptop, as both crash pretty fast (every 30-45 minutes) and regularly. Now I don't think it is a browser issue, even though I use a Google Chrome deviant and not Google Chrome itself. But it is not the first time I have used the browser intensely. Also today my laptop crashed while I tried to record a webcast.

Only then when my laptop restarted the "page file" settings popped-up! Otherwise I would have never noticed: They were set to **167 MB** ?! I still don't know how that could happen, as I have 6 GB of RAM!

**Browser:** SRWare Iron v.16.0.950.0, based on Chromium / Google Chrome v.16

**Laptop:** Sony Vaio Z11Z9E/B

After I changed the pagefiles size to **400 / 4000**, see:
[image: 3]

It still doesn't work and browser and laptop crash. Now I ran memtest86+ (v.4.20) and Windiag and exported all the browser extensions and their memory footprint through `about:memory`.
[image: 5]

Plus all the other information through <strike>[`about:net-internals`](http://pastebin.com/enQjWtbp)</strike> (Missing 2017-03-13). And the ProcessExplorer (v.15.11) <strike>[task list](http://pastebin.com/qJQjK5w3)</strike> (Missing 2017-03-13).

I want to mention that memtest86+.
[image: 1]
And windiag:
[image: 2]

**I did not find any RAM errors**. So either my pagefile size is still screwed or I have to search in another direction. My [sysinfo file](http://tinypaste.com/5887026e)

I want to add, recently (2 weeks), that `explorer.exe` freezes/crashes with every startup or restart of my laptop.

[image: 4]

First I tried to "kill all processes" on it, but ProcessExplorer tells me it can't restart explorer.exe. Just for your information.

If anyone is an expert on this topic, I'd appreciate if you could have a look at my log files! Sorry that part of them are in German. Ask Microsoft why... (or ask me to export and reupload them with another program).

Comment: 6 GB of RAM! Totally very much. Much more than me. Therefore I have a very hard time to think that RAM could be the reason. Therefore I voted you down. (No I don't know the reason why either). Brands models of computers ?? browser & laptop ?? both? don't get it I'm afraid.

Comment: Consider using translate.google.com for translating from german.

Comment: Olof, you can paste the *.txt / plaintext logfiles into e.g. Google Translate. Which is better, because you are gonna keep the original! I can't translate this at the moment, I'll rather invest my time trying to find a solution to get them in English right away...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was a mostly hardware-based issue:

I had the fan / insides cleaned twice (in different Sony support centers). It didn't help. In the end I had to "force" the support team to open the heat sink and reapply heat paste on the CPU. As expected, this indeed helps.

I can only recommend anyone to check with their service center, if they clean the dust in your laptop for free. I didn't do this for a year at least (when my laptop was repaired the first time). They didn't charge me for the above work, even though I'm abroad.

Answer (score 0):

If it is mostly flash based problems, test by turning off "hardware acceleration" in flash itself, see how that goes.

Generally your system is not going to have a huge problem with a small pagefile. It popping up is not normal. If you could run a full offline defrag, and reset the pagefile , and lock size so it doesnt fragment, it could be "better" but it does not require being 6-9G in most situations. The settings you show are not locked (400-4000), it isnt the best way to set, althought it would work. a balance between your settings and windows would be 1000 1000 locked.

Next testing I would do on that system is turning off some of the programs temporarily. You got how many virtual CDs mounted ? do you leave them mounted continually?

Next thing, is an analisis of how Fancy cache (shown in logs) could be effecting things.

What is paymoplus.exe? Someting related to the 50 things you got on or connected :-) you got a Lot of stuff going on and connected and running, one amazing laptop. Some of the items might not be working together as cleanly as desired.

The event log is in German, good for you, but I cant read the simple description. Are any of the application errors something important?

Fancycache shows in the log things already?? It might be wonderful but your trying to diagnose problems you need to reduce things, not add them, until it is stable. Example: why have the updaters and quickstarts and little helper things running, when having problems?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I knew the settings might not be best. I will set it on 1000/1000. As said I don't have any images mounted and never leave them mounted longer than necessary.  Paymo Plus is a timetracking software (see Google ;)) paymo.biz/paymoplus. Do you notice something about Paymo? It starts up first thing on my laptop but it usually runs OK and I didn't notice it in the ProcessExplorer. Fancycache was removed from me now!

Comment: And sorry, but the application errors should be in English even if some words are not? The description should be translateable with Google Translation. If you don't understand the application errors, maybe you probably can't help me either. ;) I personally have no practice with such logs..

Comment: I deactivated hardware acceleration now, I'll report back. (How to: "How can I display this panel again? To view the Display panel: Right-click (Windows) or Control-click (Macintosh) the application image during playback. From the context menu, select Settings. The Display panel is the first panel shown.") http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html